# How to use jQuery to find a specifc TD in a table?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 1.6.2

I am having a little trouble tweaking my jQuery.  I need to find a specific cell and change its color attribute.

The first row may or may not be the one that I am looking for. The row I am looking for may or may not have a class.  If the first row has a class of "TableSubHead", then I don't want to turn the last cell of its row yellow.  I want to move on to the following row, and turn its last cell yellow.

In pseudocode, it should read like this:

Look in the OrderHeaderTable. Find the first row that doesn't have a class of TableSubHead and turn the last cell yellow.

Here's my code

```
$("#OrderHeaderTable tr:first(:not.TableSubHead").children("td:last").css("background", "yellow");
```

Can you help me tweak it to get what I want?

Comment: I can't see your HTML, so this is a guess, but for headers you should use the `<th>` tag instead of a `<td>` with a class (either on it or it's parent `<tr>`). This makes selecting elements much easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe

```
$("#OrderHeaderTable tr:first(:not.TableSubHead")
```

should be

```
$("#OrderHeaderTable tr:not(.TableSubHead):first")
```

Comment: You believed correctly.  That makes more sense when I read it that way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
$('#OrderHeaderTable tbody tr').not('.TableSubHead')
.first().children('td :last').css('background','yellow');
```

That should return the first `tr` in OrderHeaderTable's body that does not have the 'TableSubHead' class and then set the last cell's background to yellow.

*UPDATE*

Fixed up the query a little bit after re-reading the question and added `.not()`

Comment: That big `filter` can be replaced with `.not(.TableSubHead)`.

Comment: Thanks! As you can see James' answer is less code and works perfectly.  Yours is NOW pretty clean and gets the job done too.